# Parsing XML using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

I want to access XML elements in the following document. There about 935 items AircraftReport. I know how to display all of them by using `.find()` and `.each()` but I am having trouble getting only the first 10 AircraftReports.

```
<response>
<data num_results="935">
<AircraftReport>
     <latitude>50.5</latitude>
     <longitude>-51.8</longitude>
</AircraftReport>
<AircraftReport>
     <latitude>55.9167</latitude>
     <longitude>-43.1</longitude>
</AircraftReport>
....
</data>
</response>
```

I am assuming I have to write that in a for loop. How can this be done with jQuery?

Comment: so you are using jQuery?

Comment: Correct. I used $(this).find("AircraftReport").each(function(){...} to access each element. But this approach is wrong as it displays all elements @ArunPJohny

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 ways to solve this problem... the first is to enhance the server side code to support paging where by the server will send only 10 items per request with corresponding paging details...

Another is to do it in the client side using [slice()](http://api.jquery.com/slice/)

```
$(this).find("AircraftReport").slice(0, 10).each(function(){...}
```

Comment: Slice(0,10) did the job. I appreciate your help